# Computing a column using groupby that returns a different sized pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm having a pandas issue.

My initial dataframe looks like the following

```
name   date          monthly_number
Anne   2018-01-01    1
Anne   2018-02-01    2
Anne   2019-02-01    1
John   2018-02-01    3
Ethan  2018-01-01    4
Ethan  2018-03-01    5
Mark   2018-12-01    3
Mark   2019-01-01    1
Mark   2019-02-01    2
Julie  2018-01-01    3
```

I need to add another column to the dataframe, called `monthly_total`, which contains the sum of the `monthly_number` column grouped by month (this means: I need an extra column that has, per month, the total sum of the `monthly_number` column for that month).

The sample output would be:

```
name   date          monthly_number    monthly_total
Anne   2018-01-01    1                 8
Anne   2018-02-01    2                 6
Anne   2019-02-01    1                 6
John   2018-02-01    3                 6
Ethan  2018-01-01    4                 8
Ethan  2018-03-01    5                 5
Mark   2018-12-01    3                 3
Mark   2019-01-01    1                 1
Mark   2019-02-01    2                 3
Julie  2018-01-01    3                 8
```

Note that the `monthly_total` column always contains the sum of the `monthly_number` column for the month that appears in the `date` column.

Any tips on what is the most efficient way of computing this will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please have a look at this [link] (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html). Also, could you please share what you have already tried?

Comment: I know how groupby works, but the problem is that the resulting column returns NaN values because the size of the series that a groupby returns isn't the same size as the dataframe.

Comment: So the idea would be to join the resultant on the 'name' column to get the sum broadcasted to all the rows of the original data frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with months periods by [`Series.dt.to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html) and `sum`:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

per = df['date'].dt.to_period('m')
df['monthly_total'] = df.groupby(per)['monthly_number'].transform('sum')
print (df)
    name       date  monthly_number  monthly_total
0   Anne 2018-01-01               1              8
1   Anne 2018-02-01               2              5
2   Anne 2019-02-01               1              3
3   John 2018-02-01               3              5
4  Ethan 2018-01-01               4              8
5  Ethan 2018-03-01               5              5
6   Mark 2018-12-01               3              3
7   Mark 2019-01-01               1              1
8   Mark 2019-02-01               2              3
9  Julie 2018-01-01               3              8
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df['date'].dt.to_period('m'))
0    2018-01
1    2018-02
2    2019-02
3    2018-02
4    2018-01
5    2018-03
6    2018-12
7    2019-01
8    2019-02
9    2018-01
Name: date, dtype: period[M]
```